Drawing coloured grids with predefined outlines
Using the following code from the answer to this post;
can the colour and line-thickness of the grid lines be controlled for specific locations! to produce the second drawing.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyomino}
\pgfkeys{
  /polyomino,
  p={a}{style={fill=none,draw,ultra thick}},
  p={b}{},
  p={c}{style={fill=yellow,draw,ultra thick}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\polyomino[grid]
{
  ...aaa,
  ...aaa,
  ...aaa,
  aaaaaaaaa,
  aaaaaaaaa,
  aaaaaaaaa,
  ...aaa,
  ...aaa,
  ...aaa,
  ...aaa,
  ...aaa,
  ...aaa,
  ...aaa,
  ...aaa
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}




Once you know the coordinates, you draw some colored lines …

Note that you can define different styles, not just a, which you can then use in the diagram.

@Hany The style of the grid applies to the grid as a whole. But there can be drawn on top of it, as illustrated in the answer from MS-SPO. The bottom left coordinate of the polyomino is determined by the key at, which is initially (0,0). The size of each square cell of polyomino is 1 by 1.

No big deal ...

The red one you can do the same ending with cycle OR use polyomino's features.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyomino}
\pgfkeys{
  /polyomino,
  p={a}{style={fill=none,draw,ultra thick}},
%  p={b}{},
%  p={c}{style={fill=yellow,draw,ultra thick}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\polyomino[grid]
{
  ...aaa,
  ...aaa,
  ...aaa,
  aaaaaaaaa,
  aaaaaaaaa,
  aaaaaaaaa,
  ...aaa,
  ...aaa,
  ...aaa,
  ...aaa,
  ...aaa,
  ...aaa,
  ...aaa,
  ...aaa
}
\draw[line width=5pt,cyan] (6,8) --++(3,0) --++(0,3) --++(-3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

